# How to read numbers in a file and process them as integer in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a file which consists of free space size of the drives and devices like the following:
32591253504, 33591253504, and so on. I wanted to save these numbers in integer form and then convert them to gigabytes. How can I do that in Qt? I have written the following program which stores numbers as a QString and then represents them in QTableView.

```
// Get free space of the Drives and Devices
    QFile text_file_freespace("C:/Users/lightning/Desktop/space.txt");
    text_file_freespace.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream text_stream_freespace(&text_file_freespace);
    QStringList string_list_freespace;

    while (true)
    {
        QString line = text_stream_freespace.readLine();
        if (line.isNull())
            break;
        else
            string_list_freespace.append(line);
    }

    row = 0;
    while(row < counter)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            QModelIndex index = model->index(i, 3, QModelIndex());
            QString freespace = string_list_freespace.at(i+1);
            model->setData(index, freespace);
        }
        row = row + 1;
    }
```

How can I process those numbers as integers and then convert them to gigabyte format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not possible to divide strings by numeric value, a conversion into integer must be preceded.

You can convert QString to integer by toULongLong() method,
and QString::number() static method would help you converting integers to QString.

```
QFile text_file_freespace("C:/.....space.txt");
text_file_freespace.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream text_stream_freespace(&text_file_freespace);
QStringList string_list_freespace;

while (!text_stream_freespace.atEnd())
{
    QString line = text_stream_freespace.readLine();
    auto freespace=line.toULongLong();    // convert QString to Unsigned long long
    freespace/=(1024*1024*1024);    // divide by 1GB
    string_list_freespace.push_back(QString::number(freespace));    // convert integer value to QString back and insert into list.
}
```